# How can I update specific object in embedded list using mongoengine?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

> This is my schema model

```
class Address(Document):
       street = StringField()
       city = StringField()
       country = StringField()

    class Users(Document):
       user_name = StringField()
       address = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField('Address'))
```

> This is what my object look like:

```
{
  user_name: "John",
  address: [
    {
      "street": "broadway",
      "city": "new york",
      "country": "US"
    },
    {
      "street": "weymounth",
      "city": "london",
      "country": "England"
    }
  ]
}
```

> This is my code to update the second item/object in address list:

```
new_address = Address(street="bourke", city="melbourne", country="Australia")

User.objects(id="1", address__country="England").update_one(set__address__S=new_address)
```

> But this update change the first object in embedded list instead of the second one:

```
{
  user_name: "John",
  address: [
    {
      "street": "bourke",
      "city": "melbourne",
      "country": "Australia"
    },
    {
      "street": "weymounth",
      "city": "london",
      "country": "England"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: according to this url `http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#querying-lists` this is for updating the document if you don't know about the position in list. you want to update the second element. a tedious solution might be to create a new list with the second element as your new address object and then save.

Comment: I think you must have made an error in your testing. The query statement is constructed correctly with a positional `$` operator to match with a `$set`, which does update the correct matched element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [EmbeddedDocumentListField](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html?highlight=embeddeddocumentlist#mongoengine.fields.EmbeddedDocumentListField)

```
from mongoengine import Document, StringField, EmbeddedDocumentListField, EmbeddedDocument
class Address(EmbeddedDocument):
    street = StringField()
    city = StringField()
    country = StringField()

class Users(Document):
    user_name = StringField()
    address = EmbeddedDocumentListField(Address)


addresses = []

addresses.append(Address(street="broadway", city="new york", country="US"))
addresses.append(Address(street="bourke", city="melbourne", country="Australia"))

u = Users(user_name="john", address=addresses)
u.save()

Users.objects(address__country="US").update_one(
    set__address__S=Address(street="some street", city="Paris", country="France")
    )
```

Final Doc:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59ec3c5219185b2fb4d428fa"), 
    "user_name" : "john", 
    "address" : [
        {
            "street" : "some street", 
            "city" : "Paris", 
            "country" : "France"
        }, 
        {
            "street" : "bourke", 
            "city" : "melbourne", 
            "country" : "Australia"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This work perfectly, but if you need to just update one variable from inside the list you can accomplish it by using the tag:

```
set__address__S__street = "some street"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
u = Users.objects(user_name="john").first()
u.adress.filter(country="US").update(street="some street", city="Paris", country="France")
u.save()
```

Recommendation:
Each element of the embedded list should have an ObjectId (id)